# Get unique values in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am querying my table with the following query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT [RoleId], [RoleName], [RoleDescription], [PermissionId]  
FROM [Role] 
ORDER BY [RoleName]
```

And I get the following results;

```
RoleId  RoleName    RoleDescription PermissionId
   1        Admin            CanEdit        1
   2        Admin            asdf;lkj       2
   3        Admin            al;dskfj;l     3
   4        Admin            fa;ldkfjas;d   4
  17        SuperAdmin      aslkdfja;      1
  18        SuperAdmin      asldkfa;f      2
  15        Users           alskdfj;alk    1
  16        Users           aslkdfja;sl    2
```

However, I want to get the unique values of RoleName i-e RoleName shouldn't be repeated which is already in my query results. I want to get the RoleName once. 
**How do I get unique RoleName?**

**Updated:**
I want to populate the combobox with the following results;

```
Admin
SuperAdmin
Users
```

but not not repeating (which I get already using my query

```
Admin
Admin
Admin
Admin
SuperAdmin
SuperAdmin
Users
Users
```

Comment: Using a second query? Or how do you wish to handle the RoleDescription,PermissionId values that differ?

Comment: Which `RoleDescription` and `PermissionId` you need with the distinct `RoleName`

Comment: I don't need them right now. I need to populate [RoleId], [RoleName] into combo box

Comment: @DotNetDreamer, where is RoleID in your sample data ?

Comment: it is autogenerated but I will update the question for u

Comment: I need to query like this SELECT DISTINCT [RoleId], [RoleName]
FROM [Role]
ORDER BY [RoleName]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have only Distinct RoleName then you can query the table like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [RoleName]
FROM [Role]
ORDER BY [RoleName]
```

Comment: I want [RoleId[ and [RoleName] both;

Comment: @DotNetDreamer if RoleId and RoleName are a 1 to 1 you should get the same result as suggested above. If they are not, Even with a more complicated query you would have get say, the first RoleId with distinct RoleName which won't be very useful

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT [RoleId], [RoleName]
FROM [Role]
ORDER BY [RoleName]

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are watching is little bit complicated as you are going. if you want such type of result then you might have to change your process to "**add Roles**". While you are inserting Roles from front end then there you have to check whether the rolename is being entering doesn't exists in database already. Then you can easily go the result you are seeing for with the following Query.

```
Select Distinct rolename,roleid from tblroles
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want `RoleId` as well as `RoleName`. Well, you have to *tell* the system **which** `RoleId` to pick:

```
SELECT MIN(RoleId) as RoleId, RoleName
FROM Role
GROUP BY RoleName
ORDER BY RoleName
```

In this case, I've chosen somewhat arbitrarily to use the lowest `RoleId` for each name. If there's a different rule you want to use, then you a) need to tell *us* what that rule is, and/or b) need to tell SQL Server what that rule is.